# TinyMCE-react: media is not clickable in readonly mode

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using [tinymce-react](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react), it works fine in editor mode, but when I use readonly mode with `disabled = {true}`, the video I inserted turns unclickable. ([My test site.](https://lontoone-5070b.web.app/article/yEO6B3V05mQcJuIiYm4y))

I have tried copy YouTube embed code to my source code and insertion via Tinymce editor, none of them work while in readonly mode.

```
<Editor
     disabled={true}
     readonly={true}
     init={{
         readonly: 1,
         selector: "#editor",
         plugins:
         media preview paste autolink autosave save directionality code visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount imagetools textpattern noneditable help charmap emoticons autoresize",
         toolbar: false,
         menubar: false,
         media_live_embeds: true,
     }}
></Editor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved but I don't know why.
I changed editor plugins like so:

```
<div id="editor">
                <Editor
                  disabled={true}
                  readonly={true}
                  init={{
                    readonly: 1,
                    selector: "#editor",                    
                    plugins: [
                      "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                      "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                      "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste youtube",
                      "autoresize","code","visualblocks","codesample","table",
                      ],                    
                  
                    toolbar: false,
                    menubar: false,
                    extended_valid_elements:
                      "+iframe[src|width|height|name|align|class]",
                  }}
                ></Editor>
```

It is weird that it won't work if I split plugins string to array by space, nor pass a complete string to it.